# Wordpress http 500 error on install

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, http-status-code-500

I know there are a lot of posts about this, but most of them seem to be much later on in the life of a wordpress site - mine is happening on the install.php, so I'm guessing its a more fundamenal issue.

My setup:

```
Windows 10 (1803)
Nginx (1.15.2)
PHP (7.2.9 - None Thread Safe)
MySQL (8.0 - Community)
```

The file structure - (in case it has any baring is)

```
nginx - \Development\nginx\nginx-1.15.2\
PHP   - \Development\php\php-7.2.9-nts-Win32-VC15-x64\
```

nginx is serving files from its `/html/` directory, with wordpressin a sub-directory `html/wordpress`

MySQL has a blank database called "wordpress" created, and is accessible via the command line, and the HeidiSQL application using the credentials for the wordpress site.

I know that php is working as a basic `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` file outputs the PHP info, and accessing http://127.0.0.1:8080/wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php starts the install proces with the screen requesting database info. However submitting this goes to:

http://127.0.0.1:8080/wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=2

Which throws the 500 error, blank white screen.

In the nginx access log I can see this:

`127.0.0.1 - - [28/Aug/2018:08:56:20 +0100] "POST /wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=2 HTTP/1.1" 500 5 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=1&language=en_GB" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"`

But there is nothing in the nginx error log - literally nothing, it was filled with missing favicon lines but i created a blank one to reduce the noise from that.

When `wp-config.php` is hard coded with the database info and the line `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`, accessing `install.php` gives the error 500 error - but no additional information.

Any idea what the issue is?
Could it be a file permissions issue, I'm assuming nginx is running as my windows user - which is an administrator.

UPDATE:

Windows php doesn't come with an php.ini file (why!!!) so I crabbed one from http://www.reallylinux.com/docs/php.ini and placed it int eh php root directory - this worked and i could switch on erro logging

This now gives me somethign to work on - as I'e got to the route of the issue:

```
[error] 2200#6728: *9 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP Fatal error:  
UncaughtError: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in \nginx\nginx-1.15.2\html\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php:1564
```

Any one know why mysql_connect() is undefined?

UPDATE 2:

The actual route cause of the issue was this PHP bug:

Cannot connect to mysql 8 using Php 7.2.8 (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76660)

Downgrading to PHP 7.2.7 and the issue went away... given the changes made in the accepted answer.

Comment: This is a 500 code error. Check your PHP log file to understand the problem (/var/log/php.log something like that)

Comment: @elhostis - Thanks - I checked `error_log` setting in phpinfo(), but it has *no value*, I checked the php.ini file location in phpinfo() and it says C:\windows - but its not there...which makes sense as why would php have write permissions to create that file in C;\windows.... anyone know where it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_connect()` is a function that was there till `PHP 5.2`, and was deprecated in **PHP 5.5.0**, and it was removed in **PHP 7.0.0**. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. [Ref: PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: thanks, strange that Wordpress says it requires php 7, but then in the config sets its internal reference to using `mysqli_connect()` to false. Anyway flipped that, and fixed the issue of php not looking in the correct diretory for extensions - (php for windows really need to provide a php.ini file!) but the issue is now: 'Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_init()' so I'm not 100% sure that was the route cause.

Comment: OK - flipped the wordpress boolean back so it now says `private $use_mysqli = false;` Seems wordpress needs mysqli and to be told not to use it... very odd. Its no-longer giving me 500 errors. It still doesn't work -but its obviously a differnt issue.

Comment: Have you tried using PHP-PDO , more efficient I guess

Comment: I've not tried much at all, I've never used Wordpress until now and not used PHP for over 10 years so just feeling my way through the basics at the moment.... efficiency is a long way down the line. Right now I'm missing the MS .NET WebAPI sooo much!